# Django custom Error handling

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

To enable a better error tracking I would like to generate a custom ID to any unexpected error and to expose it to api callers. For that, I wrote a custom `ErrorMixin` (where `graylogger` is a logger which sends log data over ip to a logserver as json):

```
class UnknownError(APIException):
    status_code = 500


class ErrorMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(ErrorMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

        except APIException as e:
            # catches known errors
            raise e

        except Exception as e:
            uuid = get_uuid()
            graylogger.error("{uid: {}, traceback: {} }".format(uuid, traceback.extract_stack())
            raise UnknownError(detail=uuid)
```

The Problem is:
Django somehow catches the error before I do:

**What I expect:**

```
{"uid": "123-123-123-123": "msg": "... stacktrace ... "}
```

**What I am getting is:**

The default django 500 page in non debug mode and the django stacktrace page in debug mode.

Could you please explain, why?

Comment: whats Django error? `NameError` by any chance? you have undefined variable uuid in your exception handling logic

Comment: Sorry, the `uuuid` was just a typo in my example. The Particular error is a `UnicodeDecodeError` but it does not play a role, as i am just getting the django error handling, instead of the `django-rest-framework` error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: Override the `handle_exception` method in the following way:

```
class ErrorMixin(object):

    def handle_exception(self, e):
        if isinstance(e, APIException):
            return super(ErrorMixin, self).handle_exception(e)

        else:
            uuid = get_uuid()
            return super(ErrorMixin, self).handle_exception(
                UnknownError(detail=uuid))
```